# StreamProvider not updating

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider, flutter-streambuilder

ı am working on chat page like conversation. And ı can fetch data with stream from firebase.When ı open page first time all data come but if new data added to the firebase, my ui not updating. And also when ı go to back and click again to go to conversation page new data coming.

my view model function

```
Stream<List<Message?>> getSingleConversation(conversationId) async* {
    String? userId = await _authRepository.getCurrentUserId();

    if (userId != null) {
      yield* _conversationRepository.getSingleConversation(
          conversationId, userId);
    }
  }
```

my provider route

```
MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            StreamProvider<List<Message?>>.value(
              value: _conversationViewModel.getSingleConversation(chat!.id),
              updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,
              initialData: [],
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ConversationViewModel()),
          ],
          child: ConversationPage(
            chat: chat,
            conversationId: chat.id,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

and ui

```
List<Message?> viewModelProvider = Provider.of<List<Message?>>(context);



 Widget _buildMessagesList(List<Message?> viewModelProvider) {
    return ListView(
        children: viewModelProvider.map((e) {
      return _buildMessageCard(e!);
    }).toList());
  }
```